# Can i use the navigation stack with my platform?

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"The navigation stack can only handle a differential drive and holonomicwheeled
robots. The shape of the robot must be either a square or a rectangle. "

But i have a platform, can move forward,backward and turn to the right and left (i.e. it can't move to the left or right - perpendicular to the length, without facing) . Slam gmapping work well on it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213530/can-i-use-the-navigation-stack-with-my-platform?/) by [flaminga](https://answers.ros.org/users/22598/flaminga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you have a differential drive platform. The nav stack will probably work.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [flaminga](https://answers.ros.org/users/22598/flaminga/) on 2015-07-12**:
Yes. Thanks)